# Set zero default value for null rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, null

I have this query

```
SELECT  
    LineId, [LineNumber], 
    TotalNeed, TotalMRC, TotalMIV, TotalIMIV,
    (TotalMRC - TotalMIV) as Shortage
FROM  
    (SELECT  
         LineId,[LineNumber],
         ROUND(SUM(Quantity), 3) AS TotalNeed,
         SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineId(LineId) AS TotalMRC, 
         SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineId(LineId) AS TotalMIV,
         SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineId(LineId) AS TotalIMIV
     FROM  
         [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO]
     GROUP BY 
         lineid, [LineNumber]) a
```

And these are the results :

[image]

As you can see some of my columns value are `null`. How can I set it  to `0` if the value of that is `null`?

Comment: Use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff which part of query i should use it dear friend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
  SELECT mto.LineId, mto.[LineNumber], round(sum(mto.Quantity), 3) as TotalNeed
         v.*, (v.TotalMRC - v.TotalMIV ) as Shortage
  FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO] mto CROSS APPLY
       (VALUES (ISNULL(SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineId(mto.LineId), 0),
                ISNULL(SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineId(mto.LineId), 0),
                ISNULL(SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineId(mto.LineId), 0)
               )
       ) v(TotalMRC, TotalMIV, TotalIMIV)
  GROUP BY mto.lineid, mto.[LineNumber];
```

Normally, I prefer `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()` (because the former is standard).  However, `COALESCE()` evaluates the first argument twice.  So for an expensive operation (such as a user-defined function), `ISNULL()` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `coalesce` to replace a `null` with a value:

```
SELECT  LineId,
        [LineNumber],
        TotalNeed,
        TotalMRC,
        TotalMIV,
        TotalIMIV,
        (TotalMRC - TotalMIV) as Shortage
  FROM  (
        SELECT  LineId,[LineNumber],
                round(sum(Quantity),3) as TotalNeed
                ,COALESCE(SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineId(LineId), 0) as TotalMRC
                ,COALESCE(SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineId(LineId), 0) as TotalMIV
                ,COALESCE(SPMS2.dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineId(LineId), 0)  as TotalIMIV
          FROM  [SPMS2].[dbo].[ViewMTO]
          GROUP BY lineid,[LineNumber]
        ) a
```